# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError with Python dict

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, jinja2

I'm trying to render a jinja2 template from a python dict created from a CSV file, but jinja2 is taking exception to the dict and I don't understand why.

This is the template:

```
{% for key, value in hostname.iteritems() %}
interface {{ key }}
 description {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

and this is the python code:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint
import os
import jinja2

CSVDATA_FILENAME = 'port_descriptions.csv'
TEMPLATE_FILENAME = 'cisco.j2'
hostnames = []

env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.getcwd()),
    trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True)
template = env.get_template(TEMPLATE_FILENAME)

for row in csv.DictReader(open(CSVDATA_FILENAME)):
    if row['hostname'] not in hostnames:
        hostnames.append(row['hostname'])

for hostname in hostnames:
    x = hostname
    hostname = {}
    for row in csv.DictReader(open(CSVDATA_FILENAME)):
        if x == row['hostname']:
            hostname[row['port']] = row['des']
    pprint(hostname)
    print template.render(hostname)
```

At the penultimate line `(pprint(hostname))` the code will print the hostname dictionaries as desired so I know they are there, but jinja2 won't render them.  Am I missing something obvious here, in the template maybe?
As far as I can see my code follows this - http://keepingitclassless.net/2014/03/network-config-templates-jinja2/ pretty closely, but I must be overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this example](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/intro/#basic-api-usage) in the docs, you probably need to pass your dictionary as a named keyword argument, like this: `print template.render(hostname=hostname)`

Note that only the part on the left of the equals sign is relevant to the template; you could just do `template.render(hostname={'testy': 'testy'})` and the same template would keep working.

Comment: Thankyou @Underyx I just assumed that jinja2 would know what I was refering to.  So, just to make sure I understand; it's the 'hostname' on the left that is referred to by the jinja2 template, not the hostname that refers to the dict in the python script (which could then be called anything, ie. foo, as long as template.render(hostname=foo) )?

Comment: @RMPhoenix that is correct.

This is because of how Python works (and actually, all programming languages I know): when you call, for example, `print(1 + 1)`, Python will first run everything inside the parentheses, and then send only the result to the print function, so print will only see 2, and nothing about how 2 was calculated. In your case Python evaluated `hostname`, and made the call like this: `template.render({'testy': 'testy'})`; Jinja didn't even get the chance to see what the original name was.